# Can't cd into created directory

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, directory

I am trying to mount an external drive to `/mnt/stuff` and make it so all users can read, write and `cd` into all folders and subfolders of it.

I can currently cd into `/mtn/stuff` but if I run `mkdir /mnt/stuff/asdf` and then `cd /mnt/stuff/asdf` I get the following error: `bash: cd: /mnt/stuff/asdf: Permission denied`.

The output of `ls -ld /mnt/stuff` is `drwsrwsrwx+ 1 xipoti xipoti 8 Oct 11 01:26 /mnt/stuff`.

The output of `mount | grep stuff` is `/dev/sda1 on /mnt/stuff type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)`

`getfacl /mnt/stuff{,/staff}` returns

```
getfacl: Removing
leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/stuff
# owner: xipoti
# group: xipoti
# flags: ss-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:users:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rw-
default:group::rw-
default:group:users:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rw-

getfacl: /mnt/stuff/staff: No such file or directory
```

`ls -ld /mnt/stuff/staff` gives `ls: cannot access '/mnt/stuff/staff': No such file or directory`

Output of `umask` is `0022`.

I tried changing the mount options on fstab and permissions for `/mnt/stuff` with `chmod`. Currently, the line on fstab for the drive is `UID=96da7abb-55b1-45c7-bb13-0b3c4e047892 /mnt/stuff auto rw,exec 0 2`

Comment: What is the output of `mount | grep stuff`?

Comment: What's the output of `getfacl /mnt/stuff{,/staff}` and of `ls -ld /mnt/stuff/staff` and of `umask`?

Comment: Also note that the sticky bits don't carry across mount points (if this is what you are trying to do, your question is vague on what you tried to **do** so "all user can read, write and cd"). So the external driver will have whatever permissions are on that filesystem. Depending on the filesystem (you didn't tell us what it is), you might be able to override that, see man-page for the mount options.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Comment: You created `/mnt/stuff/asdf` but check the permissions of `/mnt/stuff/staff`?! Please check for the folder you really created (or, if you did, correct your question).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but don't you need to have acl in your parameters in `/etc/fstab` for getfacl/setfacl to work correctly?